# How to explain different spirits and species within them?

Tags: worldbuilding-process, species

I’m not too sure how to explain this, but I have a universe set in a modern world where basically humans co-exist alongside supernatural beings.

I have the usual creatures and monsters like vampires, werewolves and other living species etc. and then I have spirits inspired by different folklore.

The problem I confused myself with is, I have grouped spirits into sub-categories, Examples being gods, deities, and then stuff like fairies and yokai.
I found that terms like yokai or fairy could encompass species within themselves, so I feel that I might confuse people if I group spirits by their sub-categories while others are unclassified, e.g species > fairy > spirit, as opposed to species > spirit.

They’re all spirits but I’m afraid I might confuse people if that makes sense? I don’t want fairies or yokai to be seen as an entirely different thing, basically they are types of spirits in my world lore just like deities or angels/demons are

Is this a confusing setup, or should I just refer to spirits interchangeably as a spirit/their specific species when talking about them (e.g character A is a kitsune spirit, character B is a deity spirit, and so forth) rather than using lots of terms interchangeably?
I feel like calling something a fairy on its own won’t let the reader know the character is a spirit but an entirely different being, if that makes sense.

Sorry if this is confusing, I’m really overthinking this and can’t explain properly. Any opinions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You can construct whatever categorization of things in your world you want. This makes a question where you're soliciting opinions about a thing you can literally do however you want a particularly poor fit for this site.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thanks for the edit but we do not permit questions soliciting opinions on this site.

Comment: You took a particularly hard topic to ask here ^^". Naming things are often quite personal (therefore opinion-based), and wondering about multiple things can be challenging since it lacks focus. Doesn't mean you can't ask here, but it'll need some work with the help center and some reference [questions](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help). I'm not sure I'd be able to make a viable one o_x. [...]

Comment: [...] Don't despair though, since here's one tip to dig your doubts out : Creature naming is dependent on the people who talk : Scientists will use cool looking latin names (e.g. : azurae butterflicarus of butterflicarus subgenre of main genre spiritus spiritus), most people use "common" names which can encompass multiple species (a fairy which is a spirit), and finally ignorant people use ultra-generic terms (that "thing" :p). Only scientists truly care about biological classifications ^^.

Answer (score 1):

## Classification IRL

The issue of classification is perennial in most fields, usually made up by some experts and gain traction by mass appeal. This is especially true when we are talking about things that have loose or non-existent rules.

Even biology, with their [general taxonomy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxonomy_(biology)#:%7E:text=In%20biology%2C%20taxonomy%20), has its troubles. For instance, even the definition of [species](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Species) raises problems. Nevermind trying to revamp the tree to place most-related organisms next to each other! And yet, this scheme is generally recognized as a useful tool.

## Run With Inexactitude

Your interchangable, inexact definitions can be fine! A yokai is a spirit that generally has "X," whereas a faerie generally has "Y," and a deity generally exhibits "Z." You only run into issues when you say these are *strict* definitions and then make exceptions to them.

Additionally, if it isn't important to the plot or game you are making, *it doesn't matter*. Importance is, of course, up to you as the world-builder.